# Org mode python session does not return a file name

Tags: org-mode, python

In the [following link](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-python.html) you can find the following simple example:

```
#+begin_src python :session :results file
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(3,2))
plt.plot([1,3,2])
fig.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('myfig.pdf')
'myfig.pdf' # return this to org-mode
#+end_src
```

I have the problem that the string that contains the file name is not returned. Thus, I don't get something like:

```
#+RESULTS:
[[file:images/myfig.pdf]]
```

Here is what I can see in the session's buffer:

Process Python finished

```
Python 3.4.3 (default, Feb 27 2015, 00:22:26) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.56)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> >>> >>> r/folders/kz/1c2cxn1x60n_t5p2j1p02b180000gn/T/py6499_X0''', 'exec'));
import matplotlib
>>> import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(3,2))
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(3,2))
plt.plot([1,3,2])
plt.plot([1,3,2])
fig.tight_layout()
fig.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('myfig.pdf')
plt.savefig('myfig.pdf')
'myfig.pdf' # return this to org-mode
'myfig.pdf' # return this to org-mode


open('/var/folders/kz/1c2cxn1x60n_t5p2j1p02b180000gn/T/babel-64998Up/python-6499xhD', 'w').write(str(_))
open('/var/folders/kz/1c2cxn1x60n_t5p2j1p02b180000gn/T/babel-64998Up/python-6499xhD', 'w').write(str(_))




'org_babel_python_eoe'
'org_babel_python_eoe'
>>> [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x10bc987f0>]
>>> >>> 'myfig.pdf'
>>> >>> 9
>>> >>> >>> 'org_babel_python_eoe'
>>>
```

However, the following works as expected:

```
#+begin_src python :session :results file
'./myfig.pdf' # return this to org-mode
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
[[file:./myfig.pdf]]
```

What is the problem here? How can I debug it? It seems like `matplotlib` causes some problem.

### Edit:

Same org file behaves as expected on a Linux box. The problem described above happens on Mac. So, probably it has something to do with the installed python versions. Still, I don't know how to debug it...

### Edit 2 (Debugging steps):

Ok, I'm trying to break the steps. Consider the complete example:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python :session :results file
import matplotlib             #1
matplotlib.use('Agg')         #2
import matplotlib.pyplot      #3
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(3,2)) #4
plt.plot([1,3,2])             #5
fig.tight_layout()            #6
plt.savefig('myfig.png')      #7
'myfig.png'                   #8 return this to org-mode
#+END_SRC
```

If I comment lines 1-7, then the results block is correct:

```
#+RESULTS:
[[file:myfig.png]]
```

Now, I start to add the lines in their order. Each time I exit the interpreter, so it will be a "fresh" run.

With lines 1,8: The result is correct (as can be found above)
With lines 1-2,8: Still correct
With lines 1-3,8: Result is incorrect!

```
#+RESULTS:
[[file:]]
```

Therefore, if I understand correctly, this is not a problem of the interpreter, but something else. The version of python I use is (as indicated by `import sys; sys.version` invoked from the interactive interpreter that was started by babel):

```
'3.4.3 (default, Feb 27 2015, 00:22:26) \n[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.56)]'
```

Furthermore, `matplotlib.__version__` yields: `1.4.3'

`M-x version` returns: `GNU Emacs 24.4.51.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0, NS apple-appkit-1344.72) of 2015-02-02 on Boxname` and it runs in OS X 10.10.

Maybe this additional information can help someone solve this issue?

Comment: If you run the first block and examine the `:session` buffer (probably named `*Python*`?), do you see an error?

Comment: @mankoff: No, I don't see any error. See the addition in the update.

Comment: Actually, from the log, it looks like it worked properly... `_` would refer to `'myfig.pdf'`, which is what gets written into the temporary file: `python-6499xhD`. What if instead you'd do `:results output file` and do `print 'myfig.pdf'`, will that change anything?

Comment: @wvxvw: did not help... :( Seems like the temp file holds `[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x10c0cff28>]`

Comment: Images folder exists?

Comment: I actually omitted the directory. So my intention is to have the saved image in the "current" directory. See the edit.

Comment: What if you wrap your code in a function and make that function return the file name? I'm afraid that there's something wrong with your Python interpreter, did you compile it yourself, or maybe it's some non-official build, or a build made specifically for some other program, like Cygwin or something? I.e. I suspect that `_` in your case doesn't refer to the correct value.

Comment: @wvxvw: I cannot recall anything special with my Python. In addition, note that if I only have something like `'foo.png'`, then it is parsed correctly.

Comment: Did you try to wrap that code into a function? In your Python interpreter, try the same code and then print `_` to see what it will refer to. See this answer, option 1 for the meaning of this variable: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5893946 . I suspect that it might behave differently based on how the interpreter is invoked. Maybe if it's not interactive the interpreter messes it up.

Comment: @wvxvw: Please have a look at my second edit.

Comment: Well, this will not explain why it doesn't work (now I'm starting to suspect that the matplot library binds the `_` variable. But you could force it to by replacing the last line with `_ = 'myfig.png'`.

Comment: It also doesn't help... Could it somehow be related to the `'org_babel_python_eoe'` string?

Comment: @DrorAtariah - Were you able to resolve this issue?