# Add caption to an image generated by a code block

Tags: org-mode

Consider the following MWE

```
#+begin_src python :session :results file
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(3,2))
plt.plot([1,3,2])
fig.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('myfig.pdf')
'myfig.pdf' # return this to org-mode
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
[[file:myfig.pdf]]
```

How can I add a caption (and maybe also name) to the generated results block that contain a figure?

Comment: You could name the block using `#+name: generate_image` for example, then use `#+caption: image caption` and on the next line `#+call: generate_image`. I think you will also need to place the Babel source block headers in the `#+call:` line instead of the original block (and make the original output nothing via `#+header: results none`).

Comment: Sounds plausible. Could you turn it into an example? I'm not sure I understand the comment completely.

Comment: @mankoff, ah, right, you could label the `#+results`, I didn't think of it.  Anyways, I'm going to add an example, just for the sake of diversity.

Comment: MWE means Minimal Working Example, I had to google that

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
#+NAME: fig:org_fig
#+BEGIN_SRC python :results file :exports results :session org_org
clf()
plot(np.sin(np.arange(0,7,0.1)))
plt.savefig('org.png', transparent=True, bbox_inches='tight')
'org.png'
#+END_SRC
#+CAPTION: Org Fig
#+LABEL: fig:org_fig
#+ATTR_LATEX: :width 0.5\textwidth
#+RESULTS: fig:org_fig
```

Order is important. Putting `+#NAME` or `+CAPTION` higher/lower may cause issues.

Comment: Can this work also for HTML export?

Comment: This works also for HTML.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that next time `Ctl-c Ctl-c` is used to evaluate the code block, it won't recognize that the existing `#+RESULTS` block is associated with the code block anymore, and it will generate a new result block - without the caption or label on it - and push the existing one down the page.

Comment: @Ken not in my version of Org (8.3.2).

Comment: @mankoff Sorry, you're right, I was doing the labeling wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the example I had in mind:

```
* Example
  #+name: example_plot
  #+begin_src python :exports none
    import matplotlib
    matplotlib.use('Agg')
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    fig = plt.figure(figsize = (3, 2))
    plt.plot([1, 3, 2])
    fig.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig('myfig.pdf')
    'myfig.pdf'
  #+end_src

* Example output
  #+caption: This is an example plot
  #+label: example-label
  call_example_plot[:session]()[:results file :exports results]
```

Exported to LaTeX it produces:

```
% Created 2015-05-05 Tue 18:53
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\tolerance=1000
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\author{wvxvw}
\date{\today}
\title{test-plot}
\hypersetup{
  pdfkeywords={},
  pdfsubject={},
  pdfcreator={Emacs 25.0.50.1 (Org mode 8.2.2)}}
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\section{Example}
\label{sec-1}
\section{Example output}
\label{sec-2}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{myfig.pdf}
\caption{\label{example-label}This is an example plot}
\end{figure}
% Emacs 25.0.50.1 (Org mode 8.2.2)
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but maybe you have an idea regarding this one: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/11075/org-mode-python-session-does-not-return-a-file-name